# Pivoting a sub-dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

Say we have a dataframe like the following 6 columns

```
C1 C2 C3   A  B  C
 x  y  z  10  5  1
 r  s  t   0  0  0 
 u  v  z   1  0  0
```

I am hoping to convert it to get the following result:

```
C1 C2 C3  P   V 
 x  y  z  A  10 
 x  y  z  B   5
 x  y  z  C   1
 u  v  z  A   1
```

I think one can pivot the dataframe to get this result, but I am having difficulty accomplishing this. How can I use `pivot_table` or `pivot` to accomplish this transformation?

Comment: I think you want [`melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.melt.html), which is the opposite of `pivot`

Comment: Check out pandas [melt](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.melt.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use [`melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.melt.html) + [`query`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.query.html)

```
pd.melt(df, 'C1 C2 C3'.split(), list('ABC'), 'P', 'V').query('V != 0')

  C1 C2 C3  P   V
0  x  y  z  A  10
2  u  v  z  A   1
3  x  y  z  B   5
6  x  y  z  C   1
```